# How to create tree graph in R

Tags: r

I was wondering it is possible to create something like tree diagram using imported data table (utf-8 coded) similar to this:

```
col0   col1              col2     col3    col4
name    <NA>             <NA>     <NA>      NA
name   dog, cat, bird    dog      Canis     3
name   dog, cat, bird    cat      Feline    3
name   dog, cat, bird    bird     Avis      4
```

I try use this code sample:

```
library(rpart)
raw = subset(dataset, select=c("col1","col2","col3"))
formula = col1 ~ col3
fit = rpart(formula, method="class", data=raw)
```

But I get error like:  "number of rows of matrices must match" or in other cases this pop up: "Error: unexpected '>' in ”>"

In the end I'm trying get diagram that are more or less like a picture below:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the package **diagrammer** to give you an image like this:

[image]

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  col0="name",
  col1=c(NA, "dog, cat, bird", "dog, cat, bird", "dog, cat, bird"),
  col2=c(NA, "dog", "cat", "bird"),
  col3=c(NA, "Canis", "Feline", "Avis"),
  col4=c(NA, 3, 3, 4),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# remove rows with missing values
sub <- dataset[!is.na(dataset$col1), ]

uniquenodes <- unique(c(sub$col1, sub$col3))

library(DiagrammeR)

nodes <- create_nodes(nodes=seq(uniquenodes), type="number", label=uniquenodes)

edges <- create_edges(from=match(sub$col1, uniquenodes),
  to=match(sub$col3, uniquenodes), rel="related")

g <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes, edges_df=edges)

render_graph(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

With igraph:

```
df <- df[df$col1 != '<NA>',]
species <- union(df$col1, df$col3)
df <- df[c('col1', 'col3')]
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = species)
plot(g,vertex.size=95, vertex.label.dist=0.5, vertex.color="green", 
     edge.arrow.size=0.5, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g, root='dog,cat,bird'))
```

[image]